# IE7 and jQuery (1.8.3) not compatible

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am hiding an element in my javascript :

```
$download_btn = jQuery('a#menu_download_btn');
...
$download_btn.hide();
```

It works fine for all my browsers/version but IE7. Are they simple not compatible ?

Thanks

Comment: just check if you have duplicate `id's` on your page sometimes it gives problem in `IE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 7 is compatible with jQuery (1.8.3). below link will let you know the browser support for the jQuery versions.
http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 0):

Well, jquery.com says they support IE 6+ for jQuery 1.X (http://jquery.com/browser-support/). I think You should try to hide div another way.

1. You can try to detach() div and append() it or set html() of the parent when You want to show div.
2. You can try to hide div by setting css('display', 'none') and css('display', 'your_display) for show.
3. I think You should try toggle() either.

You should also check if your html and script is ok. Also console.log is a problem for ie so remove them if any.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was linked to duplicate ids.